# combining and contrasting time course GLMs using R

Tags: r, time-series, generalized-linear-model, contrasts

I am analyzing some time course data in which I have set up a GLM using R for each subject. Each GLM I want to run is an attempt to extract estimates of different behavioral conditions effects on the time series, and each GLM is all within a single individual.

```
glm(dilation~happy+fear+neutral+post_decision, data=dilation_data)
```

the matrix looks similar to this, only it has about 50,000 time points (so the same number of rows):

```
dilation = intercept happy fear neutral post_decision        
0.3          1        0     0     0        0      
0.5          1        0.2   0     0        0    
0.6          1        0.8   0     0        0     
0.9          1        1     0     0        0      
0.5          1        0.4   0     0        0.2    
0.8          1        0.2   0     0        0.4     
1.2          1        0     0     0        0.8     
0.9          1        0     0     0        1
```

1. Is it going to be a problem in terms of contrasting different estimates or the model in general if my time courses of the regressors slightly overlap (see happy and post_decision in example above), do they need to be made orthogonal for the glm to be correct? If so what is the best way to do this using R.
2. I have 40 subjects, my plan is to run a glm for each subject and combine and contrast the different outputs. What is the best way in which I can contrast the difference between the GLM outputs for happy-neutral for example, and is it recommended to do this before or after combining subjects?
3. What is the ideal way for me to combine the 40 GLMs, so I have an average estimate of the change from baseline for happy lets say, and what test would be ideal for trying to say happy is significantly different than neutral based on this initial GLM for all 40 subjects?